# $wpdb->insert() does not Insert record in a table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm trying to understand and get hold of the $wpdb global object but can't seem to make it work. Basically, I'm trying to insert a single record into a custom table in wordpress DB. Instead of creating your own connection string and using that, I've seen the Global $wpdb object do the trick for us. I followed the codex example and tried to do it on my own but failed. I don't get any error but the record does not insert as well. It been hours figuring the issue. Your help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Code:**

```
<?php
class Listings{

    private $buisnessName;
    private $contactName;
    private $categories;
    private $websiteURL;
    private $telephoneNum;
    private $address;
    private $socialLinks;
    private $shortDescription;
    private $images;
    private $fullDescription;
    private $tags;

    function __construct($buisnessName, $contactName, $categories, $websiteURL, $telephoneNum,$address,$socialLinks, $shortDescription, $images, $fullDescription,$tags){

        $this->buisnessName = $buisnessName;
        $this->contactName = $contactName;
        $this->categories = $categories;
        $this->websiteURL = $websiteURL;
        $this->telephoneNum = $telephoneNum;
        $this->address = $address;
        $this->socialLinks = $socialLinks;
        $this->shortDescription = $shortDescription;
        $this->images = $images;
        $this->fullDescription = $fullDescription;
        $this->tags = $tags;        
    }

    function Insert_Listing(){
        global $wpdb;
        $wpdb->insert('wp_listings_info', array("Buisness_Name" => $this->buisnessName,"Contact_Name" => $this->contactName, "Categories" => $this->categories, "Website_URL" => $this->websiteURL, "Telephone_Number" => $this->telephoneNum, "Address" => $this->address, "Social_Network_Links" => $this->socialLinks, "Short_Description" => $this->shortDescription, "Images" => $this->images, "Full_Description" => $this->fullDescription, "Tags" => $this->tags), array("%s", "%s","%s", "%s","%s", "%s","%s", "%s","%s", "%s","%s"));
    }

}
?>
```

**Table Structure:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_listings_info` (
`L_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Business_Name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`Contact_Name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`Categories` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`Website_URL` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
`Telephone_Number` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`Address` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
`Social_Network_Links` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
`Short_Description` text NOT NULL,
`Images` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`Full_Description` text NOT NULL,
`Tags` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`L_ID`)
)
```

and I'm calling the object of the class like this:

```
$listingObj = new Listings($buisnessName, $contactName, $categories, $websiteURL, $telephoneNum,$address, $socialLinks, $shortDescription, $images, $fullDescription,$tags);
$listingObj->Insert_Listing();
```

Again I'm saying that I'm not getting any error at all, It's just the code does not insert the record as well. Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Business_Name` is **not** the same as `Buisness_Name` (i/s switched around). Fix it in your WP query.

```
$wpdb->insert('wp_listings_info', array("Buisness_Name" => $this->buisnessName ..
//                                         ^^
```

And your `create` statement:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_listings_info` (
...
`Business_Name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
// ^^
...
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Though I copy-pasted it but still made a mistake :/
However, I still keep on getting an error But I see 2 records of the same value are inserted each time I run the script. Although, I'm just calling the insert function once. Strange.

Comment: WordPress database error: []
INSERT INTO `wp_listings_info` (`Business_Name`,`Contact_Name`,`Categories`,`Website_URL`,`Telephone_Number`,`Address`,`Social_Network_Links`,`Short_Description`,`Images`,`Full_Description`,`Tags`) VALUES ('My Buisness Name','My Buisness Contact Name','My Categories','My Website URL','1234567','My Address','My Social Links','My Short Descriptions','My images Path','My Full Description','My Tags comma seperated')

Comment: Can you plz help me and let me know why the code is inserting 2 rows in my Table. Although I'm only calling the constructor and insert function once ??

Comment: The truth is that you aren't. I'd tell you to try to run `print_r(debug_backtrace())` inside the constructor/insert function to see if you create the class elsewhere.